# Problem to add calender from web in ubuntu 18.04!

Tags: 18.04, calendar

Recently I install ubuntu 18.04 and I am trying to add [This Hackerrank calender](http://www.hackerrank.com/calendar/cal.ics)  on my laptop. But when I add the URL they ask to enter my credentials. I enter my ubuntu username and password but then nothing happened.

How can I add this anyone can help?

Sorry for poor English .....

Answer (score 0):

You may try downloading the `.ics` file and use `From file` option to add that calendar.[image: Add options]